# MS Access retrieving most recent sale

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am kinda rusty on my SQL and as MS Access is somewhat limited, I am going crazy trying to make this query:

[image: example]

As an example, I have a `master` table that records all the products, another table that stores all the `sales`.  I want to retrieve the **most recent sale by product**, ie, where the `Date` is the `MAX`.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: I did attempt, I was able to do this:

SELECT [Product].product_code, Max(Sale.date) AS Teste
FROM [Product] INNER JOIN Sale ON [Product].pk_product_id = Sale.fk_product_id
GROUP BY [Product].product_code;

Yet I was unable to join it with other tables when attempting a WHERE clause referring to this attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can get the last sales record:

```
select s.*
from sales as s
where s.saledate = (select max(s2.saledate) from sales as s2 where s2.fk_product_code = s.product_code);
```

You should be able to figure out how to put this into a query to get the rest of the information you want.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, after adapting it as I have blank saledates I was able to solve this problem.